# iOS: Timestamps from today (and tomorrow) @ 0:00:00am

Tags: objective-c, timestamp, nsdate

I want to create a timestamp from today at 0 am (and for tomorrow). Can anybody give some code how I can get this as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 12:00am this morning, use `NSCalendar` to get day, month, and year, and then use those date components (which don't include time) to get a `NSDate`:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:now];
NSDate *thisMorning = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

To get 12:00am tomorrow, add one day:

```
NSDate *tomorrowMorning = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:1 toDate:thisMorning options:0];
```

To convert these to strings, use `NSDateFormatter`.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;

NSString *thisMorningString = [formatter stringFromDate:thisMorning];
NSString *tomorrowMorningString = [formatter stringFromDate:tomorrowMorning];
```

Obviously, use whatever `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` (or `dateFormat` string) that you want.

---

If you want the number of seconds since 1970, that would be

```
NSTimeInterval thisMorningIntervalSince1970 = [thisMorning timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval tomorrowMorningIntervalSince1970 = [tomorrowMorning timeIntervalSince1970];
```

If you want those as strings, it would be either:

```
NSString *thisMorningTimeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", thisMorningIntervalSince1970];
NSString *tomorrowMorningTimeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tomorrowMorningIntervalSince1970];
```

Or

```
NSString *thisMorningTimeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", (long long) thisMorningIntervalSince1970];
NSString *tomorrowMorningTimeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", (long long) tomorrowMorningIntervalSince1970];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have.

```
 NSString * yourDate = @"2015-02-13 00:00:00";   
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate * date = [dateFormat dateFromString:yourDate]; 
 NSString * timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[date timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

Comment: I want a timestamp (the date in secs since 1970)

Comment: nice! and how can I use the date instead of a set string?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize.

Comment: @Tim Yes, of course you can use the date.
If you want to check how to charge the date without an NSString check Rob's post.